# Does the component of a vector in $L_{2}$ need to be within whatever limits I place upon it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

In $L^{2} (a,b)$ let there be a vector $V(x_{1},x_{2},\dots)$. We have $x_{i}$ defined as:

$$x_{i}\  = \ \langle e_{i}|V \rangle$$

Where $e_{i}$ is the orthonormal basis set. Since $V$ is a part of $L^{2}$ $(a,b)$ does it mean $x_{i} \in (a,b)$? If not, what is the significance of $(a,b)$?

Comment: It is supposed to denote that its functions are defined on the interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: Hilbert space is determined up to isometric isomorphism by the cardinality of an orthonormal basis. Since $L^2((a,b))$ is separable for all $a<b$, you'll never be able to tell what $a$ and $b$ are from the Hilbert space structure alone. Heck, you can't even tell $L^2((a,b))$ apart from $L^2((a,b)^n)$ for any $n$.